# Does corona supports SWF format

Tags: cross-platform, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I want to develop an app in Corona SDK, in which I want to split screen of the device into multiple sub screen.

In Each screen I can display/play any of the following format.

Graphics:
JPEG
PNG
Flash swf
Gif
pdf

Video:
MPEG
mp4

Audio formats:
mp3
wav

Please tell me is it possible to run these formats in Corona App & second thing is it possible to play these different thing in a single screen.
Like Windows 8 has Live tiles.

That means, in screen tile 'A' I want to play video, in tile 'B' a pdf, etc.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona SDK does not support SWF, FLA, FLV or any form of flash. There used to be a 3rd party product that could convert a SWF to Corona Lua code, but I don't know how up to date it is, if it's even available. Once we changed our software to use our new Graphics 2.0 format, it broke a lot of older 3rd party software packages.

We do not support Animated GIF's but should unoffically load a non-animated version.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Texture Packer. I have used this in one of my apps to import swf files and convert them into Image Sheets

https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/getting-started/corona-imagesheet

Its pretty great!